# How do I process enormous numbers?

Tags: bignum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most efficient implementation of a large number class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094/most-efficient-implementation-of-a-large-number-class)

Suppose I needed to calculate 2^150000. Obviously that number is going to exceed the size of an int, float, or double. How can I make a data type that allows normal math functions but exceeds the basic number types?

If this is a "depends which language you use" kind of deal. I will say C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See

[Most efficient implementation of a large number class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094/most-efficient-implementation-of-a-large-number-class)

for some leads.

Comment: I originally tried to search for a post that already existed, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

If C# is not cast in stone, and you want something that just works out of the box, then there are several options. The one I know best is [Python](http://www.python.org/), but I think that languages like Scheme and Ruby support large numbers, too.

Python: `2**150000`. Prints the result after about 1 second.

If you want free mathematics software, look at Maxima or Sage.

Comment: just a datapoint, mzscheme feels far faster than Python in calculating (expt 2 150000) vs. 2**150000

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider using Frink, which is a language with the native capability of dealing with measurement units.
It computes 2^150000 without difficulty, deals with fractions (e.g. 1/3+2/5 --> 11/15), computes 3 meters + 2 inch --> 3.0508 m and is a full programming language.

Frink - Copyright 2000-2008 Alan Eliasen, eliasen@mindspring.com
 http://futureboy.us/frinkdocs/

Answer (score 1):

Several languages have built in support for arbitrary large numbers. You could use Mathematica, for example. I tried your example in Mathematica, and the result has 45,155 digits. I tried the same example with `bc` on a Unix machine. bc supports extended precision, but not that extended; it bombed on the example.

Answer (score 1):

Lisp is your friend. Default biginteger numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I find it very frustrating to use a language without arbitrarily large numbers: it seems nonsensical to be able to use ordinary operators like addition on most numbers, but to have to switch to method calls on a BigInt instance simply because of its size.

A whole bunch of languages have more complete numeric towers, and seamlessly coerce when needed; e.g., Allegro Common Lisp evaluates and prints all 45,155 digits of (expt 2 150000) in 1ms.

```
cl-user(2): (time (expt 2 150000))
; cpu time (non-gc) 0 msec user, 0 msec system
; cpu time (gc)     0 msec user, 0 msec system
; cpu time (total)  0 msec user, 0 msec system
; real time  1 msec
; space allocation:
;  2 cons cells, 18,784 other bytes, 0 static bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a product in C called calc which is an arbitrary precision calculator. I used it once when working as a researcher and found it fairly straightforward to use...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/calc/

It can be programmed for difficult or long calculations and can accept arguments from the command line. In interactive mode, it accepts one command at a time, and displays the answer.

Ordinarily the commands are simply expressions such as:

```
    3 * (4 + 1)
```

and calc will print:

```
    15
```

Calc does the arithmetic operators +, -, /, * as well as ^ (exponentiation), % (modulus) and // (integer divide).

For example:

```
    3 * 19 ^ 43 - 1
```

will produce:

```
    29075426613099201338473141505176993450849249622191102976
```

Calc values can be VERY large. For example:

```
    2 ^ 23209 - 1
```

will print:

```
    402874115778988778181873329071 ... loads of digits ... 3779264511
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C# but I do know the Ruby programming language has the BigDemical class that seems to allow numbers of unlimited size.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a bignum library.  If you need to implement a bignum library in another language you can at least use the Python one as reference for validating your work.  Note that bignums have a few implementation gotchas that aren't immediately obvious if you don't know what you're looking for.